# 'DbFunctions' does not contain a definition for 'ILike'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I am working a asp.net core 6.0 project

`query = query.Where(d => EF.Functions.ILike(d.Id.ToString(), $"%{keyword}%"));`

When I try to use `ILike`,

I got this error `'DbFunctions' does not contain a definition for 'ILike' and no accessible extension method 'ILike' accepting a first argument of type 'DbFunctions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I added reference `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` too.

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Why this error occurs?

Comment: For SQL Server, it is Functions.Like

Answer (score 2):

The `ILIKE` keyword is specific to PostgreSQL, so you need to use the PostgreSQL provider ([Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/)) for the `EF.Functions.ILike` function to be available.